# javascript function edge cases solving

Tags: javascript

```js
function doNf(num, left, right) {
  let numStr = num.toString();
  const numArray = numStr.split('.');
  let leftPart = numArray[0];   // Grab the left part of numStr

  // Determine how many times to loop based on left and leftPart
  const timesToLoop = left - leftPart.length;

  if (typeof right === 'undefined') {
    for (let i = 0; i < timesToLoop; i++) {
      numStr = '0' + numStr;   // Add a 0 to the beginning of numStr
    }
    return numStr;
  } else {
    let rightRounded = num.toFixed(right);    // Round num to right decimals
    numStr = rightRounded.toString();
    for (let i = 0; i < timesToLoop; i++) {
      numStr = '0' + numStr;   // Add a 0 to the beginning of numStr
    }
  }
  return numStr;
}
```

This Function is basically a modified rounding-off function. It works correctly but there are few edge cases that i am unable to handle, need help with that.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const n = Math.pow(10, -i);
    console.log(i, n, doNf(n, 4, 2));
}
```

This gives output like:

```
0 1 0001.00
1 0.1 0000.10 
2 0.01 0000.01
3 0.001 0000.00 
4 0.0001 0000.00
5 0.00001 0000.00
6 0.000001 0000.00
7 1e-7 0.00
8 1e-8 0.00
9 1e-9 0.00
```

case 7,8,9 are behaving incorrectly.
there should be exactly 4 zeros before decimal since `left = 4`. I even checked that the typeof those `0.00` is string, but i am unable to figure out why the concatanation is not happening??

Comment: Could you please name the variables better?

Comment: Your code doesn't work when `num.toString()` uses exponential notation. It expects there to be a `.` in the number, but `1e-7` has no `.`. You have to add code to check for this.

Comment: Or use `toFixed()` instead of `toString()`.

Comment: What is the expected output for 100000? For 1e38?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using `toString()` as that will produce scientific notation. In that case no `.` is found in the string, which breaks the algorithm.

Instead, use `toFixed` immediately and pad the result at the left so it has the required digits before the decimal point.

There are maybe some boundary cases to deal with:

- When `right` is 0, there will be no decimal point in the result; the padding should take this into account
- When `left` is 0, you maybe want the results to *start* with a decimal point. `toFixed` always produces at least one digit before the decimal point.
- When the given number has an absolute value is too great to be represented in the given format, the `left` restriction is ignored (as `padLeft` will do).

```js
function doNf(num, left, right) {
    let s = num.toFixed(right).padStart(left+right+!!right, "0");
    return left ? s : s.replace(/^0/, ""); 
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let n = 1 / 10 ** i;
    console.log(i, n, doNf(n, 4, 2));
}
```